# How can I add git to an existing project which hasn't been tracked but git has a full history

Tags: git, git-svn

I have some projects that were tracked in SVN, and then imported to git with a full history.

I would like to be able to use the existing project locally, which only uses svn, while starting to track in git. The versions should be identical, minus any ignored files. I have done the following, but wondered if there was a better way to do this:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "backing up"
git branch -m backup
git checkout -b master
git remote add origin {repo}
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Comment: You want to use SVN for "remote" repo, and Git for local repo, right?

Comment: Are you saying you want the project mastered in both SVN and git? That seems perilous. Better to pick one.

Comment: Actually, the project was in svn, converting to Git for local and remote. So the situation I have is untracked files locally, with a full history of the same files on the remote. I want to add the remote repo without setting the project back up if possible, so keeping any config files and the like not checked into the repo.

Comment: Ok, that helps clarify. And you say that what you have worked for you. Even if there are better ways, it's typically at one-time per project activity, so unless you have a lot of migrated projects with untracked files, optimizing the process is of limited value.

Comment: Having said that, I'd probably clone the new repo, and rsync old repo to new, excluding the .svn directories. Or, I'd do the migration when I didn't have any new files in the old repo.

Comment: I'm looking at maybe two dozen projects for a few users each, as I'm viewed as the guru on this. Since it's a pretty simple task and a one time thing, it isn't a big deal, I just wanted to learn more git if applicable.

Answer (score 0):

> So the situation I have is untracked files locally, with a full history of the same files on the remote.

Whenever you have a set of file which:

- is not in a Git repository
- but represent an evolution of said Git repository

You can:

- clone that repo
- git add those file, using the `--work-tree` parameter of `git` itself

That is:

```
cd /path/to/cloned/repo
git --work-tree=/path/to/untracked/files add .
# commit, push
```